# MongoView Creation gives Sort exceeded memory limit of 33554432 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

My Mongo Aggregation query gives following errors

**Stacktrace:
Database error!
|____/ Mongo Server error (MongoQueryException): Query failed with error code 292 and error message 'PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Sort exceeded memory limit of 33554432 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.' on**

Below is my view aggregation pipeline

```
[{
    $sort: {
        event_trigger_date: -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "profile_id": "$profile_id"
        },
        data: {
            $first: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $unset: "_id"
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$data"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "profile_id": 1
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'profile_event',
        localField: 'profile_id',
        foreignField: 'profile_id',
        as: 'profile_event_data'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "profile_id": "$profile_id"
        },
        data: {
            $first: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$data"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        profile_id: 1,
        profile_event_data: 1,
        event_type_set: {
            $concatArrays: ["$profile_event_data.event_type"]
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        _id: {
            $concat: ["ACTIONS_NOT_COMPLETED_0X:", "$profile_id"]
        },
        event_type: "ACTIONS_NOT_COMPLETED_NX",
        event_trigger_date: "$$NOW",
        event_occurence: 0,
        trigger_status: "SILENT"
    }
}, {
    $unset: "event_exists"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'profile_personal_info',
        localField: 'profile_id',
        foreignField: 'profile_id',
        as: 'personal_info'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        profile_id: 1,
        event_type: 1,
        event_trigger_date: 1,
        event_occurence: 1,
        trigger_status: 1,
        event_type_set: 1,
        personal_info: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$personal_info", 0]
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        oldest_personal_info_created_date: {
            $trunc: {
                $divide: [{
                    $subtract: ["$$NOW", '$personal_info.created_date']
                }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24]
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        created_date: {
            $trunc: {
                $divide: [{
                    $subtract: ["$$NOW", '$event_trigger_date']
                }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24]
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        event_type: 1,
        profile_id: 1,
        event_trigger_date: 1,
        profile_event_data: 1,
        event_type_set: 1,
        event_occurence: 1,
        trigger_status: 1,
        category_value: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $eq: ["$oldest_personal_info_created_date", null]
                },
                then: "$created_date",
                else: "$oldest_personal_info_created_date"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        profile_id: 1,
        event_type: 1,
        event_type_set: 1,
        event_trigger_date: 1,
        event_occurence: 1,
        trigger_status: 1,
        category_value: 1,
        "event_exists": {
            $in: ["ACTIONS_NOT_COMPLETED_NX", "$event_type_set"]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        event_exists: {
            $ne: true
        }
    }
}, {
    $unset: ["event_exists", "event_type_set"]
}]
```

Articles suggested issue is because of sort logic consuming more than 100 Mb of RAM Space so i removed sort from my aggregation pipeline but it gave me following error

**Stacktrace:
|____/ Mongo Server error (MongoQueryException): Query failed with error code 4568 and error message 'PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Total size of documents in profile_event matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 16793600 bytes' on server**

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit can u please help with this issue

Comment: Have you tried [allowDiskUse](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/)?

Comment: Beyond the memory issues, I'm wondering if the aggregation pipeline can be simplified *a lot*.  Can you provide samples of your collections and the desired output/logic?

Comment: @ray can u suggest how to use allowDiskUse : true in code-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695407/how-to-add-allowdiskuse-true-in-spring-mongo-view-creation